# Troubleshooting PHPMailer SMTP() connection error, telnet command failure

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm troubleshooting my SMTP() connection failure. I've already opened up port 587 on my server, I have openssl enabled. My DNS is working and when I ping the server I get the correct response. Going through the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide I tried running the command: '**telnet smtp.gmail.com 587**' but the connection **timed out**.

I am connected via SSH to my server as a **non-root** user (it's not my server).

But when I am connected as the **root** user I get the correct response.

Why is this? And is this possibly why I am getting my SMTP() connection error?

*edit:
When I run:

```
php -i
```

Under 'Configuration' I see these two lines:

SMTP => localhost => localhost

smtp_port => 25 => 25

Should this be changed to port 587?

Comment: It sounds like your non-root user is somehow being denied access to DNS or some other network resource. If it's failing when run as your PHP user, it probably is the same problem.

Comment: should that smtp_port setting be changed or is that correct?

Comment: is this something that I check in cPanel? I've only used MAMP, first time with a real server. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: PHPMailer only uses the settings from php.ini if it's sending using `mail()`, but it sounds like you're using SMTP, so it will not be affecting this. Try using PHP's `getdnsrr()` function to see if you have any luck doing DNS lookups directly from your own PHP code. If that fails the same way, you'll know it's a system problem.